# stratified sample on ranges

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table_1, that has data such as:

```
Range Start   Range End   Frequency   
10                   20          90   
20                   30          68   
30                   40         314   
40                   40         191 (here, it means we have just 40 as data point repeating 191 times)
```

table_2:

```
group     value   
10        56.1   
10        88.3   
20        53   
20        20   
30        55
```

I need to get the stratified sample on the basis of range from table_1, the table_2 can have millions of rows but the result should be restricted to just 10k points.

Tried below query:

```
SELECT   
    d.*   
FROM   
    (   
        SELECT   
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(   
                                PARTITION BY group   
                                ORDER BY group   
                            ) AS seqnum,   
            COUNT(*) OVER() AS ct,   
            COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY group) AS cpt,   
            group, value   
        FROM   
            table_2 d   
    ) d   
WHERE   
    seqnum < 10000 * ( cpt * 1.0 / ct )
```

but a bit confused with the analytics functions usage here.

Expecting 10k records as a stratified sample from table_2:

Result table:

```
group     value   
10       56.1   
20       53   
20        20   
30       55
```

Comment: Why there is only one record of group 10 in result table?

Comment: the result table is just for an example. Basically, the result table should contain the subset(stratified sample)  of records from table_2

Comment: Are the 10000 results supposed to be proportional based on the frequencies, so there are ~5 times as many values from the 30-40 range as there are from the 20-30 range (i.e. 314/68 = 4.617... time as many)? Also does a row with group 20 get counted in the 10-20 range, or the 20-30 range, or both? (One might assume that you include values >= start and < end; but then 40-40 would be empty...)

Comment: @SurendraSingh . . . Your question doesn't make sense.  Your first table has a total frequency of 663, but you are asking for 10,000 rows.  Where do the remaining 9,337 rows come from?

Comment: Why don't you use `sample clause`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065953 ?

Answer (score 1):

It means you need atleast one record of each group and more records on random basis then try this:

```
SELECT GROUP, VALUE FROM
(SELECT T2.GROUP, T2.VALUE, 
ROW_NUMBER() 
OVER (PARTITION BY T2.GROUP ORDER BY NULL) AS RN
FROM TABLE_1 T1
JOIN TABLE_2 T2
ON(T1.RANGE = T2.GROUP))
WHERE RN = 1 OR
CASE WHEN RN > 1 
AND RN = CEIL(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,RN))
THEN 1 END = 1
FETCH FIRST 10000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Here, `Rownum` is taken on random basis for each group and then result is taking `rownum` 1 and other `rownum` if they fulfill random condition.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you want - which is by no means certain - then I think you want to get a maximum of 10000 rows, with the number of group values proportional to the frequencies. So you can get the number of rows you want from each range with:

```
select range_start, range_end, frequency,
  frequency/sum(frequency) over () as proportion,
  floor(10000 * frequency/sum(frequency) over ()) as limit
from table_1;

RANGE_START  RANGE_END  FREQUENCY PROPORTION      LIMIT
----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         10         20         90 .135746606       1357
         20         30         68 .102564103       1025
         30         40        314 .473604827       4736
         40         40        191 .288084465       2880
```

Those limits don't quite add up to 10000; you could go slightly above with `ceil` instead of `floor`.

You can then assign a nominal row number to each entry in `table_2` based on which range it is in, and then restrict the number of rows from that range via that limit:

```
with cte1 (range_start, range_end, limit) as (
  select range_start, range_end, floor(10000 * frequency/sum(frequency) over ())
  from table_1
),
cte2 (grp, value, limit, rn) as (
  select t2.grp, t2.value, cte1.limit,
    row_number() over (partition by cte1.range_start order by t2.value) as rn
  from cte1
  join table_2 t2
  on (cte1.range_end > cte1.range_start and t2.grp >= cte1.range_start and t2.grp < cte1.range_end)
  or (cte1.range_end = cte1.range_start and t2.grp = cte1.range_start)
)
select grp, value
from cte2
where rn <= limit;

...

9998 rows selected.
```

I've used `order by t2.value` in the `row_number()` call because it isn't clear how you want to pick which rows in the range you actually want; you might want to order by `dbms_random.value` or something else.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=4fb6875a73cb6e317cf7c224595865fc) with some artificial data.