# Stratified sampling into 3 sets considering unbalance

Tags: pandas, numpy, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I have looked into [Stratified sample in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44114463/stratified-sampling-in-pandas), [stratified sampling on ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57604428/stratified-sample-on-ranges), among others and they don't assess my issue specifically, as I'm looking to split the data into 3 sets randomly.

I have an unbalanced dataframe of 10k rows, 10% is positive class, 90% negative class. I'm trying to figure out a way to split this dataframe into 3 datasets, as 60%, 20%, 20% of the dataframe considering the unbalance. However, this split has to be **random and non-replaceable**, which means if I put together the 3 datasets, it has to be equal to the original dataframe.

Usually I would use `train_test_split()` but it only works if you are looking to split into two, not three datasets.

Any suggestions?

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"target" : np.random.choice([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1], size=10000)}, index=range(0,10000,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using train_test_split() twice?
1st time, using `train_size=0.6`, obtaining a 60% training set and 40% (test + valid) set.
2nd time, using `train_size=0.5`, obtaining a 50%*40%=20% validation and 20% test.
Is this workaround valid for you?

Comment: it's a workaround, but strictly speaking is not random as the last split is a subsplit from a previous split.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more?  If by random, you mean that every sample has a 60% chance of being in the train, 20% chance of being in the validation and 20% chance of being the test, and this holds for all samples just the same, then the method above should be random. Why do you think it isn't?